# Переменный тэг в Haml

Tags: haml

имеется фрагмент кода примерно следующего вида:

```
-if true
  %foo
   .container
     %a(href='#')
-else 
  %bar
   .container
     %a(href='#')
```

как можно укоротить данную запись таким образом, чтобы тэги foo и bar менялись в зависимости от условия, но при этом не пришлось бы писать дважды их содержимое?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В реализации HAML на Ruby можно это сделать [через хелпер `haml_tag`](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/haml/haml/Haml%2FHelpers%3Ahaml_tag):

```
- haml_tag(true ? "foo" : "bar") do
  .container
    %a(href='#')
```

В самом языке HAML разруливание таких ситуаций не предусмотрено, это отдано на откуп исполняемому коду в шаблонах.

Comment: @КириллСтронько либо примеры в документации неверные, либо что-то не так на вашей стороне. Боюсь, у меня сейчас нет возможности проверить оба варианта.

Comment: разобрался, мой глюк. всё правильно, спасибо :)

Comment: @КириллСтронько прошу галочку :)